# Share SqlConnection between TableAdapters

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.5, tableadapter

My form calls multiple `TableAdapter` objects to fill a local, common `DataSet` with relevant rows (see below).

```
private void frm_TrialsFromOrder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.trialTableAdapter.FillBy(this.myDataSet.trialTable, this.trial_id);
    this.orderTableAdapter.FillBy(this.myDataSet.orderTable, this.order_id);
}
```

When executing the program, the SQL Server Profiler shows:

1. Audit Logon
2. SQL:Batch (SELECT ... FROM trialTable ...)
3. Audit Logoff
4. Audit Logon
5. SQL:Batch (SELECT ... FROM orderTable ...)
6. Audit Logoff

How can I configure multiple `TableAdapter` objects to use the same `SqlConnection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to. The `SqlConnection` object is built to be created, inside of a `using` as a best practice, used, and then disposed (hence the `using` statement). Do not share connection objects. The operation of pooling connections to ensure that it's not expensive is handled by the server.

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx):

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

Do make sure you're setting the `Pooling` property on the connection string to `true` so that pooling is enabled; that would defeat the purpose otherwise (in general).